# extract group membership from JSON (SharePoint Designer)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, json

I have created a workflow that calls `https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/site/_api/Web/CurrentUser` and stores the user ID in a variable called userId.

I am then passing that userId into another call 
`/_api/Web/getUserbyId([%Variable: userId%])/Groups`.
Now I am storing the results of the second call in a variable called JSONResultsGroup

Next I want to get the Title of the groups from the dictionary. 
I am using 
`Get d/Title from Variable: JSONResultsGroup (Output to Variable: dataset )`

Then counting the items in the dataset and storing the count in resultsCount variable.

For troubleshooting I am logging the count of the variable, but I never seem to get any results. I have tried many different variations in the Get `d/Title` call but cant seem to get the path of the json correct.

[image]

Actual workflow:

```
Call ://site.sharepoint.com/sites/ksec... HTTP web service with request (ResponseContent to Variable: JSONResults |ResponseHeaders to Variable: responseHeaders |ResponseStatusCode to Variable: responseCode )

Get Id from Variable: JSONResults (Output to Variable: userId )

Log User ID Is [%Variable: userId%] to the workflow history list

Call ://site.sharepoint.com/sites/ksec... HTTP web service with request (ResponseContent to Variable: JSONResultsGroup |ResponseHeaders to Variable: responseHeadersGroup |ResponseStatusCode to Variable: responseCode1 )

Log 2nd call is [%Variable: responseCode1%]  to the workflow history list

Get d/Title from Variable: JSONResultsGroup (Output to Variable: dataset )

Count Items in Variable: dataset (Output to Variable: resultsCount )

Log resultscount [%Variable: resultsCount%] to the workflow history list
```

Comment: My biggest breakthroughs on this came when I modeled my queries in an outside tool like SmartBear's SoapUI, or chrome apps like postman or boomerang. You likely are getting back a dictionary with a different architecture than you expect.

Comment: I do have Postman installed, i will run the query through there and look at results. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You are on the right track. d/Title is actually "". You are accurately pulling that. The next step might be to track down something like d/entry('1')/content/properties/Title/__text. There are some other things you may need to do like getting d/entry into another dictionary so you can loop through it. you can loop and pull i/content/properties/Title/__text

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
Get d/results([%numIndex%])/Title from Variable: JSONResultsGroup (Output to Variable: dataset )
```